# Hold selected state of checkbox in pagination

Tags: php, javascript

If I check some checkboxes on page 1 and then click *Next* to go to page 2 and then come back to page 1, the selected checkboxes are no longer checked. Is there any way to resolve this in PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: store them in session. We can't give u a sol'n unless u show us some code

Comment: keep it in session or just append the selected value to url

Comment: Why not store the desired state in session and use it on the next page?

Comment: he should use get or post instead of using session i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhm.. i would probably go for an AJAX solution.

```
<script>
function saveMe(){
//ajax function which calls a page that sets the session data
}
</script>
<input onclick="saveMe()" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['chk'])){echo "checked";} ?> id="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the data need to be accessed from different pages, you have to *persist* it somehow. The easier option is using the session store, or you can use a table in your database (note that the two strategies are not so different when you go to the bare, since you can easy back the session store with a table in your database). Your problem is basically the same as the shopping cart in ecommerce sites.

Note that if you choose the session and the data is stored inside an object, you may need to provide a way to serialize/deserialize it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to create pagination using jquery because when you reload page to come back from page2 or ... 
you will see your selected check box will be unchecked.

Here a reference for you to make jquery data table with pagination
 http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/dataTables/example_multi_col_sort.html
http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/04/best-ajax-jquery-pagination-plugin-tutorial-with-example-demo/

Comment: Pagination is server side, not jquery. Unless you load all of the data in a single page and then break it up with jQuery, which kind of defeats the purpose of pagination.